# The ability to solve the multivariate nonlinear equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polynomials

For *m* nonlinear polynomial equations with *n* variables and the highest degree 3, how is the current ability to solve such equations? In the webpage of IBM *cplex*, it says that:

> IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimizer has solved problems with millions of constraints and variables.

Does it represent the highest level to solve such equations? If not, what is the biggest *m* and *n* that can be solved?

I'm sorry that I'm asking about the systems of equations, not optimization.

Comment: it seems you can solve anything you like, given infinite time and able hardware...

Comment: Are you asking about solving systems of equations or optimization?  Cplex solves linear or quadratic optimization problems, not systems of polynomial equations.

Comment: Thx. I mean systems of equations...

Comment: You can typically get  numerical solutions using Newton-type methods, especially if you have a good idea of where to look for a solution.  Some problems are harder than others, though.  The number of variables is not necessarily correlated to the difficulty, as long as an $n \times n$ matrix will fit in your computer's memory.

Comment: In other words, if I design an encryption system, I'd like to know  the size of *m* and *n* to ensure the security of the system. Therefore, it relates to the current computing power of today's computer, right?